# Custom Content Provider

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

How can I make a custom content provider in android?Give me a simple example

Comment: Your question is hopeless vague and demonstrates not even the slightest effort to find the answer yourself. http://www.google.com/search?q=custom+content+provider+in+android might help some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Whenever you have a question about Android development basics always consult the website dedicated to it. That said, take a look at this [article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html)

Answer (score 1):

Android Developers Guide has a good information about Content providers [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-providers.html).

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link [here](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/writing-your-own-contentprovider/). May be it is useful for you.